# how to start a remote process with command line arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I was playing around with WMI to try to get this to work, but I've had 3 issues.

1: Anything I start doesn't show up with an application window on the remote system.

2: Most of the system's I've tried i'm getting access denied messages on.

3: How do I pass command line arguments O_O.

Answer (score 2):

[This *Hey, Scripting Guy!* article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept05/hey0906.mspx) explains #1 and suggests a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing but maybe take a look at the SysInteral's [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from Mark Russinovich.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make remote WMI calls (and dealing with the security issues that arise from it), see if you can use [rexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490989.aspx), which handles its own authentication.  You can find a daemon service for NT, 2000, XP, 2003, etc. in the MKS Toolkit.

By default, services do not have access to the user's window station; checking "Log On > Allow service to interact with desktop" will enable this.  (Though on Server 2008 and Vista, these windows are still forced to a separate, non-user window station regardless.)